# Adding a URL parameter (?p=234) to a file on Amazon Cloudfront doesn't force a refresh of the file

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have JS and CSS files being served through Amazon Cloudfront. Up until now I was using my own server running Varnish, and when I updated any JS or CSS file or I had to do to use that new version was to increase a counter on a URL param on the request for that file.

So the URL of the file being included would go from .../file.css?r=1 to .../file.css?r=2 and Varnish would think of that as a new file, request it and cache it and serve it from cache from that point on.

With Cloudfront I'm realizing it doesn't work like that, it still serves the old cached file (and I keep getting "hit from Cloudfront" on the HTTP response).

Any idea if I can change the behavior of Cloudfront for this?

Anything else I can do that doesn't imply actually changing the name of the file everytime I update the file? I also don't want to use cache invalidations through Cloudfront's API. I think that's too much work for what I'm trying to do here, and there's a limited amount of (free) requests per month I can make.

Comment: Use "Query String Forwarding and Caching" in the Cache Behavior Settings. Set the value to "Forward all, cache based on all" if you want Cloudfront to ask the source for a new file each time there is a query param, or "Forward all, cache based on whitelist" if you only want Cloudfront to get the new version depending on a whitelist of query params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you were about a month too early... in mid-May of 2012, Amazon announced that you could start using query strings to identify objects in your cloud front cache.

Here's a link to the announcement on their blog: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-dynamic-content.html

Unfortunately, I don't see any links in my quick googling that describes how exactly you can do this but I'm sure it's buried in their documentation or control panel somewhere.

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: I dont think this feature was made to get around cache, but rather as a way to create static cache from dynamic content.

Comment: Saw it, it's exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you want to avoid renaming the files, invalidation through CloudFront's API seems to be the only available option at the moment. The pain of renaming the files can be minimized by automating deploy process, however.

Comment: Instead of using this invalidation, you could also add the parameter in the URL as part of the querypath. With some URL rewriting this works perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer, no.  A CDN should be used for static assets that do not change often.

From their [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html?r=1095):

> When CloudFront requests an object from the origin server, it removes any query string parameters.

Make sure your server is set up to properly pass `Expires` headers and/or `Cache-Control: max-age` headers.  We currently use max-age=1800

Comment: Completely disagree with this.  Many folks in the web community use query strings as "cache breakers" to get around cached versions of assets that need to be bypasses (such as a bug fix in your js file that you've set the expiration for 30 days in the future).  The same goes for css files, images, and anything else you'd host off a cdn.  The fact is, static assets do change and you need this mechanism to ignore any items previously cached on the client.

Comment: You seem to be interpreting me saying "do not change often" as "never change". I can see how the term "often" can be rather subjective.
Cloudfront removes the querystring when making requests to origin (by default - though they now support passing it through ).
That does not mean you can't still use them to bust browser cache.  
For the other issues you mentioned, you have the ability to invalidate objects on the cdn ( for bug fixes, etc ) and should be using versioning for assets that do change more often.

Comment: Yeah, you should be invalidating your cache instead of trying to get around it. Trying to get around it is a hack, and a hack is, well... dirty and hackish.. Frowned upon by many folks in the web community

Comment: I see your point and I really think we're mostly saying the same thing.  One problem with versioning by file name is that you pollute your project/file system/etc with stale files.  I used to work on an asset heavy site (hundreds of millions of assets) and you don't want to have to keep versions of those files around in source control, try to figure out which ones are stale from an admin/replication standpoint, yada, yada, yada.  Ultimately, the flexibility of being able to choose which works best for you and your project is what's important.

Comment: Yeah - hope my reply didn't read harshly, wasn't intended.  But agreed.  On the flip side, we use our application servers as custom origin so we can also support GZIP. I prefer that people can not pass through a querystring and force CF to hit my servers before TTL expires - I dont want the extra load.  Each his own.  Am glad they support passing the Query String through.  Now if only they would support GZIP on S3...